# google analytics vs google tag manager; can we implement both?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, seo, google-tag-manager

what's difference between google analytics and tag manager? i understand that in tag manager we can create tags and firing rules etc. but can i use/install both google analytics and tag manager scripts in the same website?

we use google analytics to drill down many kinds of data such as demographics, locations, browser version, OS etc.

we use tag manager to count number of downloads (like how many times a particular pdf file has been downloaded), how many times a button on the form has been clicked etc.

so my question is, can i install both google analytics and tag manager scripts in the same websites? what's the best practice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to webmaster pro

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But be sure to add GA tag with the same ID only once (using GTM or directly).

GTM implementation gives you much more flexibility with tags configuration and less dependence on developers.

Comment: Are there any pros/cons if implementing both tag manager and analytics separately?.. I guess it easier to have tracking to different analytics account for development/staging/production servers

Comment: If your concern is only about different development environments then you can use environments in GTM to separate it. Also you can set GA tracking ID based on hostname or environment.